# npm install windows-build-tools failed this is probably harmless

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm-windows

```
$ set "PYTHON_MIRROR=http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/python" && npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall D:\Program Data\nodejs\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js



Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\spiri\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
[>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\spiri\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.

Starting installation...
AssignProcessToJobObject: (87) The parameter is incorrect.
npm WARN rollback Rolling back windows-build-tools@5.2.2 failed (this is probably harmless): EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\Program Data\nodejs\node_modules\windows-build-tools'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2147483651
npm ERR! windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall: `node ./dist/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2147483651
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\spiri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-28T15_16_17_617Z-debug.log
```

**This error still occurs when using powershell**

**Nodejs installed using nvm-windows,but this problem also occurs when installed through the official website**

Answer (score 1):

This is due to nvm-windows is not installed in the C drive caused by the installation of other locations will lead to no permission to deal with, so use the default installation can be